# ¿Cuál es la palabra en español para "Mortar And Pestle"?

Tags: vocabulario, pronombres, vocabulario-técnico

### Estoy intentando traducir los subtítulos de una imagen de inglés a español.

> I am attempting to translate the captions on an image from English to Spanish

[image: EDUCATIONAL_IMAGE]

¿Cuál es la palabra en espanol para "Mortar And Pestle"?

Answer (score 1):

**SI SU LICUADORA DEJA DE FUNCIONAR**

[image]

**USTED PUEDE USAR UN MORTERO Y UN MAZO**

[image]

**P.D.** Un mortero es un pequeño utensilio de cocina compuesto por  un cuenco cóncavo y un "**mazo**", también llamado "maja", "maneta", "martillo", "clava", "porra" o "mano" para "**macerar**", "majar", aplastar, triturar o mezclar los alimentos o condimentarlos.

Comment: @user13229973 They are practically the same, soaking the food in aromatic liquid (oils, vinegars, fruit juice or wine) with the aim of softening it, acquiring a certain smell and cooking. While for the very orthodox, the difference is that the objective of "Marinating" is to soften, aromatize and enhance the flavor of the food that is marinated, on the contrary, the "Macerate" technique allows extracting the juices or soluble parts of the food.

Comment: @user13229973 Practicamente son iguales, remojar el alimento en líquido aromático (aceites, vinagres, zumo de frutas o vino) con el objetivo de que se ablande, adquiera un determinado olor y se cocine. Mientras para los muy ortodoxos, la diferencia esta en que el objetivo de "Marinar"  es ablandar, aromatizar y potenciar el sabor del alimento que se marina, por contra la técnica del "Macerado" permite extraer los jugos o partes solubles del alimento.

Comment: @Diego Thanks for the kind explanations in both English and Spanish. Your two-way translations are always enormously helpful in my learning.

Comment: Diego, eres muy, muy simpático y no quiero corregir tu inglés pero hay una serie de cositas que no van en inglés. :)

Comment: @ 今夜九 Llevas razón, el mortero es  el utensilio de madera, piedra o metal, a manera de vaso o cuenco. Sin embargo cuando se hace una descripción del mismo para facilitar su comprensión general, siempre se atiende a ese cuenco junto a un mazo, maja, porra, muddler o mano de mortero que habitualmente lo acompaña, ya que sin este esencial elemento el vaso o cuenco por si solo queda desmerecido y desprovisto de su función. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0):

Además de [mortero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortero_(utensilio)), palabra que tiene muchos otros significados, se puede llamar [almirez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almirez), término exclusivamente culinario. Una variante típica de México, hecha de piedra, se llama [molcajete](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molcajete).

Por cierto, en ninguna receta de cocina se menciona la maza. Se entiende que el mortero o el almirez vienen acompañados de ella. Así que:

*You can use a mortar and pestle* = *Puede usar un almirez*